# Baer sum and endomorphisms

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I work in an Abelian category. If I take the Baer sum $M' + M''$ of two extensions $M'$ and $M''$ of $
M_2$ by $M_1$, i.e.,
$$ 0 \to M_1 \to M' \to M_2 \to 0$$
is exact, and the same for $M''$, then what do I know about $\mathrm{End}(M' + M'')$? Do I have any access to it? I know everything I want about the other objects (I know $\mathrm{End}(M')$, $\mathrm{End}(M'')$, $\mathrm{End}(M_1)$ and $\mathrm{End}(M_2)$, and also all of their $\mathrm{Hom}$ sets, for instance). I use the definition of Baer sum as successive pullback and pushout of $M' \oplus M''$ by the diagonal and codiagonal maps on $M_2$ and $M_1$, so a more general question is: what do I know about the endomorphism ring of the pullback / pushout of two objects, if I know the objects involved?

I posted the same question on [StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612746/baer-sum-and-endomorphisms?noredirect=1#comment7431230_3612746) but did not get any answers or comments so far.

Comment: The corresponding post on [math.se]: [Baer sum and endomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3612746). (It is recommended to [link the posts to each other](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638) when posting on multiple sites.)

Comment: I will also point out that the tag (abstract-algebra) is deprecated on MO, see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/abstract-algebra/info). It is also recommended to use [at least on top-level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1457/why-are-mo-tags-formatted-as-they-are). Perhaps some users who look at this question can suggest suitable tags.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!